# Iterate Through Map of Maps in Terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, nested-loops

I need to build a list of `templatefile`'s like this:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/assets/files_eth0.nmconnection.yaml", {
  interface-name = "eth0",
  addresses = element(values(var.virtual_machines), count.index),
  gateway = element(var.gateway, count.index % length(var.gateway)),
  dns = join(";", var.dns_servers),
  dns-search = var.domain,
  }),
templatefile("${path.module}/assets/files_etc_hostname.yaml", {
  hostname = element(keys(var.virtual_machines), count.index),
  }),
```

by iterating over a map of maps like the following:

```
variable templatefiles {
  default = {
    "files_eth0.nmconnection.yaml" = {
      "interface-name" = "eth0",
      "addresses" = "element(values(var.virtual_machines), count.index)",
      "gateway" = "element(var.gateway, count.index % length(var.gateway))",
      "dns" = "join(";", var.dns_servers)",
      "dns-search" = "var.domain",
    },
    "files_etc_hostname.yaml" = {
      "hostname" = "host1"
    }
  }
}
```

I've done something similar with a list of files:

```
file("${path.module}/assets/files_90-disable-console-logs.yaml"),
file("${path.module}/assets/files_90-disable-auto-updates.yaml"),
```

...but would like to expand this to `templatefiles` (above).

Here's the code I've done for the list of `files`:

**main.tf**

```
variable files {
  default = [
    "files_90-disable-auto-updates.yaml",
    "files_90-disable-console-logs.yaml",
  ]
}

output "snippets" {
  value = flatten(module.ingition_snippets.files)
}
```

**modules/main.tf**

```
variable files {}

resource "null_resource" "files" {
  for_each = toset(var.files)
  triggers = {
    snippet = file("${path.module}/assets/${each.value}")
  }
}

output "files" {
  value = [for s in null_resource.files: s.triggers.*.snippet]
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these use-cases can be met without using any `resource` blocks at all, because the necessary features are built in to the Terraform language.

Here is a shorter way to write the example with static files:

```
variable "files" {
  type = set(string)
}

output "files" {
  value = tomap({
    for fn in var.files : fn => file("${path.module}/assets/${fn}")
  })
}
```

The above would produce a map from filenames to file contents, so the calling module can more easily access the individual file contents.

We can adapt that for `templatefile` like this:

```
variable "template_files" {
  # We can't write down a type constraint for this case
  # because each file might have a different set of
  # template variables, but our later code will expect
  # this to be a mapping type, like the default value
  # you shared in your comment, and will fail if not.
  type = any
}

output "files" {
  value = tomap({
    for fn, vars in var.template_files : fn => templatefile("${path.module}/assets/${fn}", vars)
  })
}
```

Again, the result will be a map from filename to the result of rendering the template with the given variables.

---

If your goal is to build a module for rendering templates from a source directory to publish somewhere, you might find the module [`hashicorp/dir/template`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-template-dir) useful. It combines `fileset`, `file`, and `templatefile` in a way that is hopefully convenient for static website publishing and similar use-cases. (At the time I write this the module is transitioning from being in my personal GitHub account to being in the HashiCorp organization, so if you look at it soon after you may see some turbulence as the docs get updated, etc.)

Comment: Oh, wow!  This works flawlessly.  Thank you so much!  I definitely over-complicated the problem.